Validar numeros y letras incluyendo espacios en c#
He intentado validar los datos de mis textbox mediante este if
if (e.KeyChar >= 32 && e.KeyChar <= 64 || (e.KeyChar >= 91 && e.KeyChar <= 96) || (e.KeyChar >= 123 && e.KeyChar <= 255)) /* || Significa or*/ /*Esto lo hice con los valores de la tabla ascii*/
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ingrese unicamente letras por favor", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}

if ((e.KeyChar >= 32 && e.KeyChar <= 47) || (e.KeyChar >= 58 && e.KeyChar <= 255))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ingrese solo números por favor", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}

Sin embargo a la hora de iniciar el programa no me permite agregar espacios en los textbox, actualmente estoy codificando un proyecto de gestión de datos en un hospital ficticio, lo tengo como proyecto personal. Si alguien puede ayudarme o brindarme consejos sobre como validar numeros y letras en mis textbox incluyendo espacios seria de gran ayuda!!!.

Tienes las siguientes funciones a tu disposición:

char.IsLetter(char): Devuelve true si es una letra
char.IsNumber(char): Devuelve true si es un número
char.IsLetterOrDigit(char): Es la combinación de los 2 de arriba. Devuelve true si es un número o una letra
char.IsWhiteSpace(char): Devuelve true si es un espacio en blanco

Digamos que quieres permitir solo caracteres alfanumericos y el espacio:
if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) && char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
{
    //todo bien
}
else
{
    //caracter no valido
}


Muchisimas gracias colega :)
